# Does CPU usage go up if steal goes up?

Tags: linux, server, devops

My VPS is currently experiencing high steal percentages and i'm currently trying to get my head around the steal thing.
My Server used to have basically no steal and used while idling about ~5% CPU, but since yesterday is experiencing very high steal (~50%) and the CPU Usage is now at about ~20% (excluding steal).

Does the CPU usage go up if steal goes up?
Will the CPU usage get back to normal (~5%) if the steal goes away or is there something happening i'm currently not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the top command to check what is hogging your CPU. Is CPU SYS used more or USE used more? Find the most used process PID, and you can kill it

Comment: Currently netdata is using most of the ressources, which hasn't been the case before. It seems like the CPU usage has multiplied since the steal is so high. For example processes that used to use about ~5% CPU now use ~15% [Netdata Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/878u87K.png).